# How to format numbers using Regular Expression and PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am practicing for regular expressions.

I was trying to format numbers using PHP and regex. I want to add comma after each 3 digits like this 111222333444 to this format 111,222,333,444 or 11222333444 to 11,222,333,444 by using PHP and Regular expression.

I searched a lot but I could not find exact solution for this.

I know that there is function in php (number_format) to do this but I want to use Regular expression and PHP to do this because I am learning regex and practicing so I want to use regex and php only.

Comment: Why do you want to use a regex for this purpose, when there's a built-in function just for that?

Comment: And what is holding you back?

Comment: I am learning Regular expression, So I Must know how to use Regular expression with PHP to do anything with strings.

Comment: Here you have something disgusting http://regex101.com/r/iJ3aK6/1

Comment: @Fede: Works for the numbers in question, but would fail for larger numbers :)

Comment: @Fade this does not work for this numbert 1222333444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a regex based solution:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(?!^)(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/m', ',', $input);
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/sY1nH4/1)

**Explanation:**

- `(?!^)` - Negative lookahead to make sure we are not at start of input
- `(?=(?:\d{3})+$)` - Positive lookahead to make sure there 1 or more of 3 digit sets following current position
- Replacement is just a literal comma
- More explanation is available at linked demo

Comment: Can you explain a bit? If OP's goal is to learn them, I think it might be good to get details here. Nice catch anyway, +1.

Comment: Sure adding explanation (got a call in while doing that)

Comment: @AlainTiemblo: The regular expression uses a lookahead to find positions within the string where the only thing to the right of it is one or more groupings of three numbers.

Comment: Is that negative lookahead at the beginning necessary? I'd take that out just change the regex to `(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))` to have it stop at decimal places, but the OP didn't really mention that as a requirement anyway.

Comment: @AmalMurali: Without `(?!^)` `111` will become `,111`

Comment: @anubhava: Ah, right. Awesome. (I gave you a +1 already :)